# What does "Realizes the operator" really mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $K,~Q$ be two groups, $K$ is abelian and $K$ is also a $\Bbb Z[Q]$-module. Then a group extension of $K$ by $Q$: $0\to K\to G\to Q\to 1$ **realizes the operator** if the scalar multiplication $Ck=\ell(C)\,k\,\ell(C)^{-1}$ for every $C\in Q,~k\in K$. ($\ell:Q\to G$ is a lifting.)

I know this definition, and I even can memorize it. However, I feel painful whenever see a theorem require it as one of its hypothesis. What does "realizes the operator" really mean? What concept does such definition want to catch? If the scalar multiplication  of the module is the same as we use a lifting to produce a conjugation of $K$, then so what?

Comment: What is $\ell$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen it expressed like that, I would say something like "induces the $Q$-module structure on $K$" or something similar.

"realizes" corresponds to my "induces" and "the operator" corresponds to "the $Q$-module structure on $K$".

Indeed, from the fact that $K$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[Q]$-module, you have one action of $Q$ on $K$ (by definition); and from the extension $0\to K\to G\to Q\to 1$ you have another one, which is given by conjugation (and, $K$ being abelian, this is well defined): that the extension "realizes the operator" is to say that those two actions of $Q$ on $K$ coïncide.

In particular, when you study group cohomology for instance, $H^2(Q,K)$ will classify the extensions of $Q$ by $K$ that "realize the operator" (or as I would put it, the extensions that induce the correct action on $K$)

Comment: Thanks. I feel more comfortable about it. On the other hand, I think the question reduces to why do we care $\Bbb Z[Q]-$module? I'd read the corresponding chapters in Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra, but having learnt the $H^2,~H^1,~Z^2,~B^2$ and bar resolution, etc, I still don't know why we suddenly want to study $\Bbb Z[Q]-$module. Can it be explained in few sentences?

Comment: Do you mean why we care about $\mathbb{Z}[Q]$-module*s* ? Well if you're interested in representations, they automatically pop up, because a $\mathbb{Z}[Q]$-module is precisely an abelian group with an action of $Q$ by automorphisms, so as soon as you try to look into representations of $Q$, you're essentially looking at $\mathbb{Z}[Q]$-modules, which is one reason they pop up. Another reason is that any extension of $Q$ by an abelian group $K$ gives rise to a $\mathbb{Z}[Q]$-module structure on $K$ as I've explained, and this structure is interesting when studying the extension

Comment: Get it! I *totally* skip the sections on representation, only studying functors, derived functors and the topics on homological algebra, such as group (co)homology, Tor and Ext. No wonder I often feel the lack of the motivation.